# Client compatibility check management

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, client-server

I'm working on a client-server application (.NET 4, WCF) that must support backwards compatibility. In other words, old clients should be compatible with new servers and vice versa. As a result, our client code is littered with statements such as:

```
if (_serverVersion > new Version(2, 1, 3))
{
    //show/hide something or call method Foo()...
}
else
{
   //show/hide something or call method Foo2()...
}
```

Obviously, this becomes somewhat of a maintenance nightmare. Luckily, we're allowed to break backwards compatibility with every minor release. When we get to a point where compatibility can be broken, I'd like to clean up the code that's in the form of the example above.

My questions:

(1) Is there a way to easily identify code blocks such as these when they are no longer "valid"? My initial thoughts were to somehow conditionally apply an Obsolete attribute based on the assembly's version. When we get to a new minor version, the Obsolete attribute would "kick-in", and all of a sudden we would have several compiler warnings pointing to these code blocks... Has anyone done anything like this? Or is there a better way to manage this?

(2) I cringe every time I see hard-coded versions such as `new Version(2, 1, 3)`. What makes things worse is that during development, we don't know the final Version that's being released, so the version checks are based on the current build number + 1 when the developer adds the check. Although this works, it's not very clean. Any ideas on how this could be improved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest at least creating a method where you can do the logic like this:

```
public static class ServerUtilities
{
    public static bool IsValidToRun(Version desiredVersion)
    {
        if (_serverVersion >= desiredVersion)
            return true;
        else if (/* your other logic to determine if they're in some acceptable range */)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, use like this:

```
if (ServerUtilities.IsValidToRun(new Version(2, 1, 3)))
{
    // Do new logic
}
else
{
    // Do old logic
}
```

If you need to centralize the versions, have a static repository of features to version mapping, so that you can call:

```
if (ServerUtilities.IsValidToRun(ServerFeatures.FancyFeatureRequiredVersion))
{
    ...
}

public static class ServerFeatures
{
    public static Version FancyFeatureRequiredVersion
    {
        get { return new Version(2, 1, 3); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! At a minimum, I think we should centralize this logic with a method like IsValidToRun. I think the ServerFeatures class is a great idea, and might help us keep track of which checks can be eliminated as new builds are put out.

Comment: @JohnRussell, that would also give you a good way to break the build on purpose. You remove a `ServerFeatures` version when you no longer need the check, compile, and then fix all the places that are broken that rely on it.

Comment: Exactly! I like it! I think I will actually make ServerFeature an enumeration and then perform the Version to ServerFeature mapping in a helper method, e.g. a big switch statement. This would allow us to re-use the same Version for multiple features and have all of that logic in one spot. IsValidToRun could then take a ServerFeature as a parameter and hopefully prevent consumers from using on the fly version objects. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to implement versioning of your service contracts: at that point you could leverage WCF's own features to ignore minor changes which do not break the client, as listed on this [Versioning Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff384251.aspx) page.

In Figure 1 you can see that when adding new parameters to an operation signature, removing parameters from an operation signature and adding new operations the client is unaffected.

In case there are still breaking changes or your client has to support both versions (please correct me if I'm wrong since I don't know your deploying strategy), you could offer different versions of the service on different endpoints and have a WCF client factory in your client code, which could then be configured to return the client for the appropriate endpoint.

At this point you have isolated the different implementations in different clients, which is probably cleaner and less a maintenance nightmare than it is now.

---

Very basic sample implementation to clear things up: suppose that we have two different contracts for our service, an old one and a new one.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service", Namespace = "http://stackoverflow.com/2012/03")]
public interface IServiceOld
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "Service", Namespace = "http://stackoverflow.com/2012/04")]
public interface IServiceNew
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    void DoAdditionalWork();
}
```

Note how both services have the same name but different namespaces.

Let's handle the issue of having a client that has to be able to support both the extended and new service and the old one. Let's assume that we want to call the DoAdditionalWork method when we previously just called DoWork, and that we want to handle the situation client-side, because hypothetically DoAdditionalWork could require some extra arguments from the client. Then the configuration of the service could be something like this:

```
<service name="ConsoleApplication1.Service">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/test/new" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication1.IServiceNew" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/test/old" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication1.IServiceOld" />
    ...
</service>
```

Fine, we have the service side, now to the interesting part: we would like to communicate with the services using the same interface. In this case I will use the old one, but you could need to put an adapter in between. Ideally, in our client code, we would do something like this:

```
IServiceOld client = *Magic*

client.DoWork();
```

The magic in this case is a simple factory like this:

```
internal class ClientFactory
{
    public IServiceOld GetClient()
    {
        string service = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Service"];
        if(service == "Old")
            return new ClientOld();
        else if(service == "New")
            return new ClientNew();

        throw  new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I delegated the decision of which client to use to the app.config, but you could insert your version check there. The implementation of ClientOld is just a regular WCF client for IServiceOld:

```
public class ClientOld : IServiceOld
{
    private IServiceOld m_Client;

    public ClientOld()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceOld>(new WSHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8732/test/old");
        m_Client = factory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        m_Client.DoWork();
    }

    ...
}
```

ClientNew instead implements the behavior we were wishing for, namely calling the DoAdditionalWork operation:

```
public class ClientNew : IServiceOld
{
    private IServiceNew m_Client;

    public ClientNew()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceNew>(new WSHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8732/test/new");
        m_Client = factory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        m_Client.DoWork();
        m_Client.DoAdditionalWork();
    }
    ...
}
```

That's it, now our client can be used like in the following example:

```
var client = new ClientFactory().GetClient();
client.DoWork();
```

What have we achieved? The code using the client is abstracted from what additional work the actual WCF client has to do and the decision about which client to use is delegated to a factory. I hope some variation/expansion of this sample suits your needs.